# Tenhho uma função Javascript fuciona o no Chrome mas não no Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma função javascript que não deixa escrever números, somente letras, no chrome ela funciona exatamente como é proposto, agora no mozilla não funciona, abaixo minha função:

```
function soletra(event) {
    var value = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^[a-záàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñ ]+$/i);
    return pattern.test(value);
}
```

eu fiz uma adaptação para funciona, porém não ficou bom que deixa algumas teclas inativa se o campo estiver em foco:

```
function soletra(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 46
        || event.keyCode == 39 ||event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 38 || event.keyCode == 40)
        return;
    var value = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^[a-záàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñ ]+$/i);
    return pattern.test(value);
}
```

e o chamado da função está assim:

```
$("#id").bind("keypress paste drop", soletra);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eu já tive esse problema com Firefox, depois de pesquisar a solução que achei foi usar isso:

```
var key = event.keyCode || event.which;
```

No caso do Firefox, se o `keyCode` não funcionar, usa o `which`, e também funciona para os outros navegadores, então você usa varável `key`. Li que em alguns eventos de teclado diferentes (keypress, keyup, etc), `keyCode` não retorna um valor, deve ser o caso do seu problema.

```js
$("#i1").bind("keypress", function(event) {
  var key = event.keyCode || event.which;
  $("#i2").val(key);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <span>Digite aqui:</span>
  <input id='i1' type='text'>
</p>

<p>
  <span>Código da tecla:</span>
  <input id='i2' type='text'>
</p>
```

Veja o exemplo na documentação do mozilla.org, que tem exatamente essa linha de código acima: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent

Referência para o SO em inglês: [event-keycode-not-working-in-firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44449946/javascript-keycodes-are-not-working-in-firefox)

Comment: Estou tentando implementa essa linha, porém ele continuar a funcionar da mesma forma obrigado pela ajuda em relação ao doc

Comment: @BrunoH aqui você pode ver um exemplo funcional: https://jsfiddle.net/jamfLktj/  e coloquei também um exemplo na resposta